# Difference between "have never heard" or "had never heard

Tags: difference

"have never heard" or "had never heard": Which one should I use in the sentence?

I was at a ceremony. Suppose my friend asks me "What do you think of the song that they have just finished playing?", can I reply "It ***was*** great, I **have /had** never heard it before."

Comment: The difference is simply one of tense.  Since the song is over (and thus in the past), use the past tense to describe it: `It was great, I had never heard it before`.  If the question was asked while the song was still playing, then it's the opposite.

Comment: Related: ['Have never seen' or 'had never seen'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/138990/)

Answer (score 1):

The song is no more playing. Hence: "It was great!" or "It has been great!" (At least if the song performance is considered.)

With the second sentence you are referring to the period of time **before** the song performance. Hence you (have) heard the song now, you are referring to a period of time prior to a past event (the song performance) and have to use Past Perfect: "I had never heard it before."

(Disclaimer: I'm not a native speaker.)